# JS/ jQuery while loop until dom element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a tabscript, which doesn't have a success handler, after it loaded the wanted page into the opened tab.

Now I want to edit the content on the client side, after the element was loaded, which would be usually done in an asynchronous function - but due to the fact that the tabscript I am using doesn't have an success handler this approach doesn't work.

This is a working solution, but it's way to slow and could end in an endless loop:

```
open_URL_in_tab();

while(true){
    if($('#part_of_loaded_page'){
        $('#part_of_loaded_page').editContent();
        break
    }
}
```

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: looping like that eats the process threads for the browser.  you'd be better off using something like `setTimeout` running every 10+ milliseconds.  if the dom element is not ready, simply call setTimeout again with the same parameters. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: you can always add a success function to the tabscript you have. Or have the tabscript fire a custom event when it is done loading then you can bind to that event to do what you want

Comment: @ps2goat [Please don't link to w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)!

Comment: I cant write a success funtion, because the license prohibits changes in the tab source...

Comment: @nietonfir I know there's a controversy, but I don't care.  If it gets the point across, I'll link to it.

Comment: did you buy tabscript? if not modify it and give original developer credit. I don't see why anyone can't edit a script to improve its usage

Comment: @nietonfir is this better? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout  I'd rather have simple sample code when I'm starting out, then move up to the more advanced stuff when necessary.

Comment: @ps2goat *thumbsup* ;-)

Comment: You don't have to change any source code on tabscript to write your own success handler on top of it. You are not changing any part of the source code.

Comment: @MattDiamant Didn't know that, thanks! But it seems like Cliff Ribaudo's attempt worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 var intervalId = undefined;
 open_URL_in_tab();
 intervalId = window.setInterval(editContent, 500);
```

Call this when you are done:

```
 window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Comment: The usage of `setInterval()` is generally frowned upon as it mostly doesn't work as expected and can trigger some interesting side-effects.

Comment: really got a link to that... I'd be interested to see more

Comment: `setInterval` works perfectly fine for his answer. `setTimeout` is not generally frowned upon.

Comment: Just google it or read it up (e.g. Javascript Ninja). First hit on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/838733

Comment: Well I guess there is this, but I wouldn't say they are 'frowning' upon it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval and Id appreciate if people don't downvote when it simply a matter of opinion... wrong answer, yeah downvote that mo fo, but opinion.. no.

Comment: Guess the person asking this question was not frowning on it :)

Comment: Literally from the link you posted "For less demanding uses (such as a trivial updater firing every 30 seconds or something), you can safely use either." He's not doing anything that's going to lock up the browser. He's just checking whether 1 DOM element exists every half second.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentiond, the while loop won't work efficiently, but timers will help you.

```
(function() {
    function checkState() {
        var success = false; // do something to check the state
        if (!success) {
            setTimeout(checkState, 50);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(checkState, 50);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can use our plugin`readyx` as following :

```
$('#waitme').readyx(function(){
   //code to run after element loading
  // $(this).css("data-status","ready"); .....
},30);
```

### demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/ojcgwnjf/2/)